# How exact is the functor "tensoring with a locally free sheaf"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k$, $\mathcal F$ a locally free $\mathcal O_X$-module. Has the functor on locally free sheaves 'tensoring with $\mathcal F$' any exactness property (is it right/left exact or not at all) ?

If $\mathcal F$ is of rank $1$, it is known that this functor is exact. What happens for greater rank ?

Comment: Exactness can be checked on stalks, but stalk-wise these are free modules and hence the functor is exact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to remove this question from the list of unanswered questions. Let $$0\to \mathcal A_1\to\mathcal A_2\to\mathcal A_3\to 0$$ be an exact sequence of $\mathcal O_X$-modules and let $\mathcal F$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $n$. Then for any $x\in X$ we have $\mathcal F_x\cong\mathcal O_x^{\oplus n}$, therefore $(\mathcal A_i\otimes\mathcal F)_x\cong(\mathcal A_i)_x^{\oplus n}$. 
The sequence
$$0\to (\mathcal A_1)_x^{\oplus n}\to(\mathcal A_2)_x^{\oplus n}\to(\mathcal A_3)_x^{\oplus n}\to 0$$ is exact, i.e. the sequence 
$$0\to (\mathcal A_1\otimes\mathcal F)_x\to(\mathcal A_2\otimes\mathcal F)_x \to (\mathcal A_3\otimes\mathcal F)_x\to 0$$
is exact. The sequence
$$0\to \mathcal A_1\otimes\mathcal F\to \mathcal A_2\otimes\mathcal F \to \mathcal A_3\otimes\mathcal F \to 0$$
is exact on stalks, therefore it is exact.

Comment: The $\mathcal{A}_i$ don't need to be locally free.

Comment: OK, I changed to $\mathcal O_X$-modules.